# HTML div alignment has gap

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem...

[image]

it's top left web page corner. There I have a `div` with background and `div` are few pixels away from edge.

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="contcont"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contcont{
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  background-image:url('bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

How can I remove the gap?

Comment: what u have to do? mention that atleast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most browsers have a default margin for the body element. So include:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

To remove all browser defaults, to begin clean, do a Google search on: 'css reset'

Comment: Body has a default margin almost everywhere, but no padding.

Comment: @kleinfreund: I agree, there won't be (m)any browsers with a body padding other than 0. But CSS resets always seem to include it. I guess it's just to be sure or it has to do with  multiple selectors. Eg `body, h1 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` where padding makes sense for h1 and is less code than defining those separately. Anyway, `padding: 0;` could be omitted.

Comment: There aren't many elements with a initial padding (lists usually have `padding-left: 40px;`).  Headings don't have one either. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Reset your css styles

Take a look on reset css file http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Here is an example, at least without your background, because I don't have it. Instead I used a black background: http://jsfiddle.net/AYjc5/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want the picture flush to the top left, so this is what you have to do

```
#contcont{
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  background-image:url('bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
body{
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-left:9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following style in your css. margin, padding and border will be inherited by all elements in the file. And you can override as and when required.

```
html, body { 
     margin: 0px; 
     padding: 0px; 
     border: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for margins and paddings, set them to zero.

Answer (score 0):

use reset by Eric Meyer

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, figure, footer, header,&nbsp;hgroup, menu, nav, section, menu,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
vertical-align:baseline;
background:transparent;
}

article, aside, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, nav, section { display:block; }

nav ul { list-style:none; }

blockquote, q { quotes:none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after { content:''; content:none; }

a { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent; }

ins { background-color:#ff9; color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

mark { background-color:#ff9; color:#000; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; }

del { text-decoration: line-through; }

abbr[title], dfn[title] { border-bottom:1px dotted #000; cursor:help; }

/* tables still need cellspacing="0" in the markup */
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }

hr { display:block; height:1px; border:0; border-top:1px solid #ccc; margin:1em 0; padding:0; }

input, select { vertical-align:middle; }
/* END RESET CSS */
```